# CodeContracts issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-contracts

Hello
I have a little issue regarding CodeContracts. I have a class library project which as a class with a method foo(string s1, string s2); 
inside the foo method, I have a Contract.Requires(s1 != null).
So if I understand the meaning of my code (yes, I just installed CodeContracts and playing with :), the contract will check the s1 != null expression during build process and in runtime, throwing ArgumentException>. 
I wanted to test the behavior, when I call foo(null, "test") from class lib project, the designer tells me about the issue, but when I call it from the winform app project, I don't get any warnings in error list window. So does this mean that code contracts works only in the project they reside and not outside?
Thanks

UPDATE

---

I forgot to mention that the preconditions I have added doesn't work in static analysis. However they do throw ArgumentException with appropriate message in runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks to MS team, I found the problem. The reason of such a strange behavior was that my assembly's name ended with ".Contracts.dll". And the problem is that static analyzer doesn't check assemblies whose names ends with that. I renamed the assembly and everything works like a charm, just like any other MS product :)

Comment: Absolute life saver, was driving me insane!

Comment: Thank you!! They need to at least add a warning or something if this is the case. Almost 5 years after this question this issue just cost me *hours*... This is the only place on the internet I found this behavior documented.

Answer (score 2):

This should work if you have `Perform Static Contract Checking` checked in your winforms project.  Also verify that `Perform Runtime Contract Checking` is checked in your class library project if you want runtime checking.

Also, in your class library project, `Contract Reference Assembly` should be set to `Build`.

From the Code Contracts documentation:

> If your project contains contracts and is referenced by other projects, we strongly recommend that you select Build under the contract reference assemby section in the properties tab for CodeContracts.
>
> This contract reference assembly is crucial to make the contracts in your project available to referencing projects. Without building a contract reference assembly, other projects cannot determine what contracts are present.

Comment: Thanks for the reply andrift. Well I have. I have checked both of them in both projects, but it doesn't work. 

The messages window says:
CodeContracts: Checked 0 assertions.


any idea?

Comment: On your class library project, did you set `Contract Reference Assembly` to `Build`?

Comment: Yes, It's set to Build in class lib project. in Winform project it's set to none

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write which version of Visual Studio you're using.
AFAIK Code Cotnract Static Analysis works with VS Premium only (i.e. Standard and Professional are not enough).