# Code Contracts on different projects

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I have a project with contracts (project A) that generates a library and another one (project B) that implements an interface from that library.

I've tried copying the contract files from project A to project B and the contracts fire at runtime without problems. But when I'm trying to reference project A from project B. The static analyzer is still working, but the runtime checks no longer work.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something I do not understand about how code contracts work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important:** this was discussed here - [CodeContracts issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292862/codecontracts-issue)

Replicated a similar project structure in a new solution. Everything worked without any problems. I still could not find what is the matter with the production solution.

Out of despair I created a new `CompanyName.ContractsDebug` library. Some test contract implementations fired the runtime checks when using that library. Then I tried going for the stupid fix, I refactored the namespace of the old contracts project (`CompanyName.Contracts`) to a new name (`CompanyName.Shared.Contracts`). And that somehow fixed everything. Very weird bug.

**Update**
I was hasty to say that moving it to `Shared.Contracts` worked. Moving it to `Shared.IContracts` did. I don't know what is the deal with the `Contracts` keyword.